# Nginx serving static files always falls back to error

Tags: nginx

I have this configuration:

```
server {
    server_name frontend-ui.something.com;

    root /var/www/frontend_ui;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
}
```

located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and is symlinked in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. Whenever I try to access it, it falls back to `nginx 404` page. Just to be sure that the configuration and nginx are being reached I changed the config to fall back to `500` instead, and it did. So, my conclusion is that the config is reached, but the static files are not served/read.

The static files:

```
root@my-server:/var/www# ls -l frontend-ui/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 bamboo bamboo 4096 Feb 28 11:59 build
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bamboo bamboo  392 Feb 28 11:59 index.html
```

The funny thing is that I have one more page being served with the exactly same configuration and permissions, but just with different subdomain name, and it works fine.

Comment: The `root` directive has an underscore, but your `ls` has a hyphen.

Comment: My goodness... That's like chasing the `;` in the code... You can post an answer, if you wish, and I'll accept it.